# Cannot use chrome_settings_overrides for overriding Search Provider

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the following declaration in my `manifest.json`, following [Google's instructions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override#others):

```
{
  ...
  "chrome_settings_overrides": {
    "search_provider": {
      "name": "My Name",
      "keyword": "My Keyword",
      "favicon_url": "icon32.png",
      "search_url": "http://example.com/Home/Search?keyword={searchTerms}",
      "encoding": "UTF-8",
      "is_default": true
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

However, I cannot load the manifest with that part at all (removing it will make it work). The message is receive is:

> Failed to load extension from:
>   D:\Chrome\SearchExtensions 
>   Empty dictionary for 'chrome_settings_overrides'.

What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way doing this?

Comment: Yes, I am testing it on Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation says about `"favicon_url"`:

> may only be omitted if `prepopulated_id` is set.

And `"favicon_url"` **must** be a fully qualified http or https url according to chromium [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/manifest_handlers/settings_overrides_handler.cc?sq=package:chromium&dr=C&rcl=1472267847&l=91):

```c
if (!CreateManifestURL(*overrides->search_provider->favicon_url)) {
  *error = ...
.........................................
// CreateManifestURL function:
if (!manifest_url->is_valid() ||
    !manifest_url->SchemeIsHTTPOrHTTPS())
  return std::unique_ptr<GURL>();  // <<<< returns an empty value that sets the error
```

Comment: Thank you so much! No idea that was the problem. That's weird of it actually.

Comment: See the updated answer. It's just that we both didn't bother reading past `optional` in the docs.

Comment: Nah, I did read about that optional part. But there is no mention that the URL must be http/https?

Comment: Not there. I've submitted a bugreport using "Report content bug" link on the bottom of that page.