# Empty dictionary for 'chrome_settings_overrides'. Could not load manifest

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created an extension with the following values for [Settings Overrides](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override) in the `manifest.json`. When I tried to "load unpacked", it "Failed to load extension". The error message was "Empty dictionary for 'chrome_settings_overrides'.". What dictionary does it mean? I cannot decode the error message.

```
  "chrome_settings_overrides": {
    "search_provider": {
      "name": "....",
      "search_url": "....",
      "suggest_url": "....",
      "keyword": "....",
      "favicon_url": "....",
      "is_default": false
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sounds like [Cannot use chrome\_settings\_overrides for overriding Search Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39178593)

Comment: @wOxxOm Yeah, the solution was similar. Even though "encoding" was marked as "optional", in the details it says that it can only be omitted when the `prepopulationid` is set. Chrome could have given an error message like "The 'encoding' property is missing" instead of cryptic "Empty dictionary for...". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `"encoding": "UTF-8",`

```
"chrome_settings_overrides": {
    "search_provider": {
      "name": "....",
      "search_url": "....",
      "suggest_url": "....",
      "keyword": "....",
      "favicon_url": "....",
      "encoding": "UTF-8",
      "is_default": false
    }
  }
```